# Euler's method question help!

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I am stuck with another question of differential equation...
this problem requires using Euler's method....
The question is

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x^2-y , h=0.1 ~\mbox{and}~ y(0)=a$$

I need to find it up to 3 steps...

Please help!

Comment: whats the problem ? i mean u just need to use the euler's formula. dats it. regarding upto 3 places i wud advice you to carry your calculations upto 5 decimal places each time, until the digit at the third place becomes equal for two consecutive steps. al the best!

Comment: and yes, i think y(0) = 0, and not a. please check.

Comment: it is 'a' that's why i got confused... y(x) must be shown in terms of a...

Comment: and what do u mean by upto 3 steps ? do u mean u hv to find y(0.3), because in this method we find the y value at a given x value depending upon which we take a suitable value of h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x^2-y,~ h=0.1 ~~\mbox{and}~ ~y(0)=a$$

We want to find 3-steps of the Euler iteration.

- $t = 0$
- $w_0 = a$
- The Euler iteration is given by $w_i = w_{i-1} + h f(x, y)$

So we have the iteration as:

$$w_i = w_{i-1} + h\left(-w_{i-1} + 0.1 x^2_{i-1}\right) = w_{i-1} + 0.1\left(-w_{i-1} + (0.1 (i-1))^2\right)$$

Writing out the first three steps, we have:

- $w_0 = a$
- $w_1 = w_0 + 0.1(-w_0 + (0.1(0))^2) = 0.9 a$
- $w_2 = w_1 + 0.1(-w_1 + (0.1(1))^2) = 0.81 a + 0.001$
- $w_3 = w_2 + 0.1(-w_2 + (0.1(2))^2) = 0.729 a + 0.0049$

We can check an example of this, for example, let $a = 1$, the iterates are:

$$w_0 = 1, w_1 = 0.9, w_2 = 0.811, w_3 = 0.7339$$

After 26-steps ($h=0.1$), the above would converge to $(x, y) = (2.6, 3.40185)$.

The exact solution for the DEQ is:

$$y(x) = e^{-x} (a+e^x (x^2-2 x+2)-2)$$

At $a = 1$, we have:

$$y(x) = e^{-x} (e^x x^2-2 e^x x+2 e^x-1)$$

At $x = 2.6$, we get $y(2.6) = 3.48573$

That is quite a bit of error, but that is numerical methods for you.

Comment: The Great Amzoti overcome the numerical method. :+)

Comment: Newton's, now Euler's method! You know your mathematicians! +1